# React Table / Material Table: Collapse columns on resizing (responsive)

Tags: reactjs, react-table, material-table

With [`react-table`](https://react-table.tanstack.com/) (or other table libraries such as Material Table), is it possible to have responsive Collapse by Columns/Rows on small devices?

For example, `react-table` supports Expanded columns which are **hard-coded:**

- React-table: https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/examples/expanding

But we need dynamic collapsing based on table width.
What we're looking for is shown in this animation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-super-responsive-table We do **not** want a horizontal scrollbar.

We're wondering if any mainstream NPM Table library has the ability to support this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`getRowId` can be helpful in solving this problem, details of it are at - https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#table-options